# Change Fugitive's Gstatus window height

Tags: git, vim

I am using Tim Pope's [Fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) and I wish to change the `:Gstatus` default height. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It loads it into the preview window, so you can set the `previewheight` option. It will however apply to all other uses of preview window (like omnicomplete) too.

```
set previewheight=20
```

Comment: I'll need to check `omnicomplete` too, never been introduced to it. Thanks, Jan!

Comment: I've set `previewheight=20` and `:Gstatus` is still ~7 rows tall. Perhaps there's a Fugitive specific setting?

Comment: it may be that, like me, you have winheight set to something large and winminheight set to something small. I think winheight wins out.

Comment: In my case (using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) to load fugitive) I have to `set previewheight=20` before `Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'` in `$MYVIMRC`.

Comment: Seems that fugitive no longer uses a preview window for this. I ended up using `map <leader>g :15split \| Gedit :<cr>` to open status in a 15 height split.

Answer (score 14):

Set normal mode key map to execute :Gstatus command and to increase window size.

```
nmap <leader>gs :Gstatus<CR><C-w>20+
```

Comment: This mostly works, but I think I have an improvement.  The problem I had is that if you happen to use <leader>gs to get back to the status window, it will keep growing.  I did some sleuthing and fugitive uses the vim preview window as the status window.  You can `set previewheight=30` and then that will set the height like the O.P. is hoping for.  It seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 5):

I use this solution:
`nnoremap <silent> <Leader>gs :Gstatus<CR>:20wincmd_<CR>`

Comment: more clean would be `:Gstatus|20wincmd_<cr>`